# Does closing a GUI in PyQt4 destroy its children Qobjects by default

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I'm trying to make a GUI that used QTimer to create a state machine, but when ever I close the GUI window the timer continues. I think I'm properly making the object that creates my Qtimer a child of the GUI but with the behavior I'm seeing it doesn't seem like it. Here is some code

```
class Ui_Form(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_Form, self).__init__()
        self.backEnd = BackEnd(self)
        self.backEnd.start()


class BackEnd(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(BackEnd,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.timer, QtCore.SIGNAL("timeout()"), self.timerHandler)


    def timerHandler(self):
        print "Im here"
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def start(self):
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def stop(self):
        self.timer.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timer does not continue when I close GUI window, it works fine, as desired... anyway, try to override close event for your Ui_Form like this:

```
def closeEvent(self):
   self.backEnd.stop()
```

I hope that helps.

Also, I've changed your main like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

in your case it might be that `Form = QtGui.QWidget()` stays alive after you close GUI window. So try that modification first.